# Why doesn't my table align properly?

Tags: tables, siunitx

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{SS}
\toprule
{$i$}&{$e_i$} \\
\midrule
1&2\\
2&3\\
3&7\\
4&43\\
5&1807
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Could someone explain me why this table looks so misaligned?

Answer (score 7):

You hadn't specified your number format or specified a default so `siunitx` defaults kicked in, as you can see in the first table the columns are centred under the heading if you use 2dp, in the second table I give `siunitx` a hint

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{SS}
\toprule
{$i$}&{$e_i$} \\
\midrule
1.01&2.34\\
2.12&3.45\\
3.11&7.22\\
4.22&43.99\\
5.&1807
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.0]S[table-format=4.0]}
\toprule
{$i$}&{$e_i$} \\
\midrule
1&2\\
2&3\\
3&7\\
4&43\\
5&1807
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very quick and well-written answer!

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of variety, here's a solution that uses David Carlisle's [dcolumn](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) package instead of the `siunitx` package. That's not meant to somehow cast shade on the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type. It's just that the `siunitx` package does a great many things in addition to providing the `S` column type. If all you require is to align numbers in the data columns on their explicit or implicit decimal markers, you may be equally well served by employing the specialized `dcolumn` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
% new code:
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{}d{1.0}d{4.0}@{}}
\toprule
i & \mc{e_i} \\
\midrule
1&2\\
2&3\\
3&7\\
4&43\\
5&1807
\end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```